# How to trigger the event listener for a div element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to simulate the clicking of the "Download the CSV data for..." button on this page https://aqicn.org/data-platform/register/ using javascript. The problem is that the button is a `<div>` with an event listener rather than a `<button>` or `<input>`.

[image]

I assume I have to use `document.dispatchEvent()` but I don't know what parameter to put. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: The parameter you should pass to the `dispatchEvent` function is an `Event. I would suggest you to use it like that: `div.dispatchEvent(new Event("click" /* you can pass any event even if it's a custom one */))`

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger an event using [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent).

```js
// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_native
const triggerNative = (el, eventName) => {
  const event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

const btn = document.querySelector('#historical-aqidata .primary.button');
const handleClick = e => console.log('clicked button...');

btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick); // Pre-existing event listener
triggerNative(btn, 'click');                // Call the event
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#historical-aqidata {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary {
  background: #0085D6;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.primary:hover {
  background: #419ED3;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 5em !important; }
```

```html
<div id="historical-aqidata">
  <div class="ui large primary button">Download the SCV data for Seoul</div>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** MDN recommends that you use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead:

> *"Many methods used with `createEvent`, such as `initCustomEvent`, are deprecated. Use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead."*

```js
// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_custom
const triggerCustom = (el, eventName, data) => {
  let event;
  if (window.CustomEvent && typeof window.CustomEvent === 'function') {
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: data });
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    event.initCustomEvent(eventName, true, true, data);
  }
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

You can call the custom function just like the native one, as the data is optional.

```js
triggerCustom(btn, 'click');
```

Comment: Your statement between the two codes seems to suggest the latter is the "instead" part, yet you stressed the first code much more. Can you therefore further explain which method (i.e. `HTMLEvents` vs `CustomEvent`) is the recommended one? You wrote `Many methods used with createEvent are deprecated`, but both your codes use `createEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest referring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) for API references.

`dispatchEvent` is used on the element you want to simulate something on; in your case, your `div` is your target because you want to simulate `click` on it.

This is how the `dispatchEvent` API is used:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('my-div');
div.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can add an Id to your div and then You can do something like below:

HTML:

```
<div id="myBtn"></div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //write your functionality here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need of using the `dispatchEvent` API, just use the native `div.addEventListener('click', () => //do something)` and you'll be good to do, this is because of the fact that divs, like buttons, can be clicked, its just that they can't be focused by default.